# DynamoDB Schema Advice

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, mobile-development

I am practicing with working with DynamoDB and other serverless tools offered by AWS. I am used to working with relational databases like MySQL so with with Dynamo has been a little bit of a challenge for me.

Basically I was looking at doing something similar to what already exists with Facebook, Instagram, Youtube, and other popular sites are doing. And that's creating a platform that allows for Users to sign up, follow others, and post media (videos and pictures) that can be liked, and commented on. For items that could be growing, like Followers, or Likes, I originally stored as Lists in their respective tables; however, I realize that may not be the best approach as DynamoDB does have a data limit. For example, if someone like Kobe Bryant joined the app, and immediately got millions of followers, the list approach may not be best.

Like this,
Media:
- MediaID
- UserID
- MediaType
- Size
- S3_URL
- Likes: {
  ...
  ...
  }
- Comments: {
  ...
  ...
  }

Would it be better to store things like this in separate tables? Or am I now thinking back to relational databases?

For example,
Media:
- MediaID
- UserID
- MediaType
- Size
- S3_URL

Media_Likes:
- LikeID
- MediaID
- UserID
- DateLiked

Media_Comments:
- CommentID
- MediaID
- UserID
- Text
- DateCommented

Or what else would be the best way to design something like this?

Comment: Check out the DynamoDB Best Practices for Managing Many-to-Many Relationships https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html